# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello I am trying to do sending message all my friend from my discord bot(Js) when ı write &acil,but when ı write this commands something is going wrong and sending so much messages and sometimes giving => TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined error

```
 require("dotenv").config();
 const fetch = require("node-fetch");
 const Discord=require("discord.js");
 const client = new Discord.Client();

 client.on("message",message =>{
  console.log("Gelen mesaj"+message.content);
  if(message.content === "&acil")
    message.client.users.cache.get('777206236986474526').send('ACİL TOPLANTI!');
    message.client.users.cache.get('675607935380094986').send('ACİL TOPLANTI!');
    message.client.users.cache.get('777206236986474526').send('ACİL TOPLANTI!');
    message.client.users.cache.get('7175607935380094986').send('ACİL TOPLANTI!');
   
    

});
```

Comment: Maybe try removing the `message` at the beginning and let it simply be `client.users.cache.get('userID').send('');` instead

Comment: ı tryied that but result is not changed

Comment: One of the IDs is wrong or the user is not in the cache